# Angular momentum of a 2-dimensional system in polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics

Say I am studying a system who's motion is restricted to a 2 dimensional plane, for example, the two body problem in a central potential. We can align its angular momentum with the z-axis and then the motion of the two bodies is restricted to the x-y plane.

In cartesian coordinates i can write down its linear momentum as $\vec{p}=p_x\hat{x}+p_y\hat{y}$. Then it's angular momentum will be given by $$\vec{L} =\vec{r}\times \vec{p}=(x\hat{x}+y\hat{y})\times (p_x\hat{x}+p_y\hat{y})$$

Now if i want to convert this expression to polar coordinates I will get
$$\vec{L}=r\hat{r}\times (P_{r}\hat{r}+P_{\phi}\hat{\phi})=rP_{\phi}\hat{r}\times \hat{\phi}=rP_{\phi}\hat{z}.$$

The last step follows because we are restricted to the plane z=0 and here $\hat{\theta}=\hat{z}$ (up to possibly a minus sign).

However, when I actually go to compute the angular momentum for the two body problem this is not what I get.

Is what i have written true? When we switch to polar coordinates is the angular momentum proportional to the angular component of the cartesian momentum?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking but what you got in $\vec L=r\vec P_\phi\hat z=mr^2\dot\phi\hat z$ is correct.

Comment: Hi Diracology, where may I find this formula $P_{\phi}=mr\dot{\phi}$ (or what assumptions does it rely on)? I need to apply this to a version of the relativistic two body problem and I am not sure if this applies.

Comment: Write the velocity in polar coordinates by by $\vec v=\frac{d}{dt}(r\hat r)$ and use $\dot{\hat r}=\dot\phi \hat \phi$.

Comment: In the two body problem, I am getting that $$P_{\phi}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}=L.$$ This is what lead me to post my question. At first it confused me since the dimensions, $[L]\neq [P]$, but $P_{\phi}$ is a generalised momentum and doesn't have the same units as a momentum, so it is completely fine that $|\vec{L}|=P_{\phi}.$

$$~$$

Am I interpretting this correctly?